# Button handler in each list item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have list whith several items. Each item contains service information and button.

[image: Image 1]

Each tender contains id and other props which I want to get after click

[image: Image 2]

How can i get specific item properties after click on the button?

UPD:

```
export default class ListFresh extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { tenders: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    elastic.search().catch(e => alert(e)).then(
      data => this.setState({tenders: data.items})
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TenderList tenders={this.state.tenders}/>
    );
  }
}

class TenderList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <div className="tender-list">
          <List items={this.props.tenders}/>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Generate tender

```
export default class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { nodes: [] };
  }

  render () {
    const data = this.props.items;
    var node;
    data.map(item => (
      console.log(item),
        node = {
            headerName : item._source.tender.title,
            isOpened: false,
            isReactComponent: true,
            items : [
              <Tender tender={item._source} id={item._id}/>
            ],
            height: 250
          },
      DATALIST.push(node)
    ));

    return (
      <div id="admin-menu">
        <ReactExpandableListView
          data={DATALIST}
          headerAttName="headerName"
          itemsAttName="items"
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: The image doesn't give us an idea of the HTML used for the buttons, can you tell us what you've tried so far and show us some of your code?

Comment: post your code.

Comment: @Jordy19 check update